# What is $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$ equal to?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $M$ be the vector space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, and let
> $$W_1 = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 0 & x \end{bmatrix}$$
> and
> $$W_2 = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
> then what is
> $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$?

1. I tried to solve it and found an element will belong to intersection
   if it's of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & y \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, so the dimension of $W_1\cap W_2$ is $1$.
2. However, if I try to use the dimension formula:
   $ \dim W_1  = 2$
   $\dim W_2 =  3$
   $\dim W_1+ \dim W_2 =  5$
   $\dim (W_1 + W_2 )  =  3$
   Because as any element there is of the form $\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & x \end{bmatrix}$. So the dim formula says $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$  should be $2+3-3 = 2$.

Where I am wrong ?

Comment: The formatting of your post is poor and hinders readability. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I modified my language bit. Have a check

Comment: An element in both $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ has the general form $\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ rather than $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & y \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: But 4th cordinate is O and ist cordinate should be equal to 4th. Isn't ?  @conan

Comment: Oops, my mistake. The real problem is that Dim$(W_{1} + W_{2})$ is $4$, not $3$. $W_{1} + W_{2}$ is the same as the space of all $2$ by $2$ matrices.

Comment: @conan but in case of W1 + w2 , ist and 4th is dependent on EACH OTHER ? 2x and x . So dim should be reduced by 1

Comment: $$W_{1} + W_{2} = \{\begin{bmatrix} x_{1} & y_{1} \\ 0 & x_{1} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} x_{2} & y_{2} \\ z_{2} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \mid x_{1}, y_{1}, x_{2}, y_{2}, z_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{\begin{bmatrix} x_{1} + x_{2} & y_{1} + y_{2} \\ z_{2} & x_{1} \end{bmatrix} \mid x_{1}, y_{1}, x_{2}, y_{2}, z_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ If I wanted the element $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, then I can chose $z_{2} = c, x_{1} = d, x_{2} = a - d, y_{1} = b/2$ and $y_{2} = b/2$.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to publish a possible answer and I edited the OP's post, I wanted to know if I could, or it could, be reverted to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate $W_1 + W_2$, you need to take the sum of arbitrary elements of $W_1$ and $W_2$, not just ones with equal values of the parameters $x$, $y$, $z$. Note that any
$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}d & b \\ 0 & d\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}a-d & 0 \\ c & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
so indeed $W_1 + W_2 = M_{2 \times 2}$, and therefore has dimension $4$.